# Android Click Listener Behaviour

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin

[Screen Grab Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKiqa.png)

This might be a stupid question.

In Android, when I swap two TextViews why don't their onClickListeners get swapped too (in working)?

The object hash codes are swapped though and so is the mListenerInfo object. (Part of View Class)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    var textView1 = TextView(this)
    var textView2 = TextView(this)

    textView1.text = "T1"
    textView2.text = "T2"

    //linear is a LinearLayout via kotlinx access

    linear.addView(textView1)
    linear.addView(textView2)

    textView1.setOnClickListener({
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, it.hashCode().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    })

    textView2.setOnClickListener({
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, it.hashCode().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    })

    val x = textView1
    textView1 = textView2
    textView2 = x

    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, textView1.hashCode().toString() +"\n" + textView1.text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show()

    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, textView2.hashCode().toString() +"\n" + textView2.text, Toast
        .LENGTH_SHORT).show()

  }
}
```

The textViews and their corresponding properties get swapped, so textView1.text returns "T2", but on clicking T1 on screen we still get the old hashcode.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I just want to understand why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because keyword "it" and all others variables in lambdas are final.

```
textView1.setOnClickListener {
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, it.hashCode().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

So, your code `it.hashCode()` refers to specific function of immutable object in your memory.
Even if you swap t1 with t2 you will call proper object and even proper listener, but `it` still refers to old object.

After swapping those views you should fix your listeners (for example by creating new ones).

Comment: Ah! Okay, variables passed to lambdas are effectively final. Thanks